# Should I set new TextureRegion for Sprite every frame?

Tags: java, animation, 2d, libgdx

The Animation guide of Libgdx is now in Deprecated part, and I found no replacement.Therefore, I intend to write a convenient `AnimatedSprite` class that extends `Sprite`. My idea is in every update (game frame), I will set new TextureRegion (or just X/Y coordinate) corresponding its image frame.

I wonder why there is no AnimatedSprite class built-in for Libgdx? Does my solution have any problem? Is there any replacement for the deprecated Sprite Animation guide?

Comment: Looking for [actions](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/scene2d#Actions)?

Comment: @StefanHanke Excuse me, how can I use `action` to solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were looking for general animation handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely set a new Region to a Sprite every frame, something like this works wonders:

```
sprite.setRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true));
```